# Tagging: should [drawing-tablet] and [wacom] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

We have:

- [Wacom](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wacom): 26 questions
- [Drawing-tablet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing-tablet): 90 questions

13 of the questions tagged [wacom](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wacom) are also tagged [drawing-tablet](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing-tablet).

To me, a Wacom is just a specific brand of drawing tablet. I know it's by far the most well-known brand and drawing tablets are often referred to as 'a wacom' even if it's a different brand. I think they should be merged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems reasonable enough but I'll wait to give others a chance to weigh in.

I'm for it though.

Comment: just a *bump* to bring this back to attention

Answer (score 2):

I was going to point out that there are questions specific to actual Wacom tablets...

But thinking about that some more I'd say that pretty much all of them are relevant to any drawing tablet. The only thing I can think of that would only be relevant to a specific brand is tech-support, which is off-topic... So I'd say it's a good idea.